# Nginx 404 not found errors

Tags: nginx

hi i am using this config file for our webuzo panel server with yeti share file host script.for this nginx config we also give the root of site path but our pages not shows its all pages show 404 error. this config file we are use on our server.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid     /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

error_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/error_log debug;


http {
    include    mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/web.access.log  main;

    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost; # change this for your server
    root /home/wshr/public_html;
    index index.php;
    client_max_body_size 5G;

    # handle requests to the API
    location ~ /api/v2/(.+)$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^/api/v2/(.*) /api/v2/index.php?_page_url=$1 last; }
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?_page_url=$1 last; }
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?_page_url=$1 last;
        }
    }

    location /files/ {
        internal;
    }

    # these locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location /core/logs/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
        deny    all;
        return  404;
    }
}




        sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush  on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    client_max_body_size 200M;

    # If your domain names are long, increase this parameter.
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    # To hide the version number in headers
    server_tokens off;

    include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

please help what i do. what i change on it 
because our all pages show 404 error only front page show fine

Comment: check that your content is in `/home/wshr/public_html;`

Comment: Show the nginx error logs and also please show which url you are browsing?